# Error while implementing collectionview inside another collectionview's header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, slideshow, xcode8

I want to implement a collection view slideshow inside another collectionview header, but when I am trying to connect the outlet of uicollectionview I am getting an error saying outlets cannot be connected to repeating variables in storyboard.

I am using xcode 8 + swift 3.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) Are you connecting the `outlet of UICollctionview` to the view controller  class. 2) Do you have custom class for `collectionview header`.

Comment: 1) No I am connecting the outlet to UICollectionView only.
2) I don't have custom class for collectionview header. I would like to make one if it resolves this issue.
    How can I make the custom collectionview class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your outlet to the custom collectionview header not to the view controller.

Your collection view cells to change dynamically; because you repeat cells and the outlet would be ambiguous. You need to **create a UICollectionView header subclass**, and create the outlets of inner collection view there.